# Can't get snake head intersect its body for gameOver - Swift 3

Tags: swift

Trying to code snake.head.frame to intersect snake.body.frame but i get an error in gameOver() func - snake body is an UIImage

Actually tried to insert snake.body.bodys[].frame and i get no error but it didnt trigger game over after intersecting snake.head.frame to snake.body.bodys[].frame

```
func gameOver() {
    if snake.head.frame.intersects(snake.body.frame) // ERROR -  {

        print("game over")
        timer.invalidate()

    }
}

// Value of type 'SnakeBody' has no member 'frame'
```

class Snake:

```
class Snake {
let head = SnakeHead()
let body = SnakeBody()

weak var mainView: UIView!
var direction = Direction.right

init(view: UIView) {
    mainView = view
    head.nextItem = body.bodys[0]


    view.addSubview(head)
    view.addSubview(body.bodys[0])
}
```

}

class SnakeBody:

```
class SnakeBody {
var startRadius: CGFloat = 20.0
var bodys = [ListBodyItem]()

init() {
    bodys.append(conBody(CGRect(x: 60, y: 90, width: 30, height: 30)))
}

func addOne(_ view: UIView) {
    let curLast = bodys.last!

    bodys.append(conBody(curLast.frame))
    curLast.nextItem = bodys.last

    view.addSubview(bodys.last!)
}

func conBody(_ frame: CGRect) -> ListBodyItem {
    let body = ListBodyItem(frame: frame)
    body.setImage(UIImage(named: "snakeBody"), for: UIControlState())
    body.clipsToBounds = true
    return body
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your own question.

> Value of type 'SnakeBody' has no member 'frame'

You are getting this error because the class `SnakeBody` has no defined `frame`. Instead, it has an array of `ListBodyItem`s which in turn have frames. One way to fix it would be to create a seperate function that checks if the snake's head is intersecting with any part of the body. It would look something like this.

Add the following method to class `SnakeBody`

```
func isIntersectingWithHead(_ frame: CGRect) -> Bool {
    var isIntersecting = false
    for item in bodys {
        if frame.intersects(item.frame) {
            isIntersecting = true
            break
        }
    }
    return isIntersecting
}
```

Then change the `gameOver` method to

```
func gameOver() {
    if snake.body.isIntersectingWithHead(snake.head.frame) {
        print("game over")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I don't know the rest of your implementation so it'll be a bit hard to tell you exactly where to call this method. Based on your provided code, I was under the impression that you were calling the `gameOver` method by using a `Timer`. Since that is not the case, I'm assuming that you would have some sort of a function that gets called periodically (or some other way) and updates the frame of the snake. You would be doing something like this in that method

```
func updateSnakeFrame() {
    //Snake's body and head frame updated here
    if isIntersectingWithHead(snake.head.frame) {
        gameOver()
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
With this implementation, your `gameOver` method would change to

```
func gameOver() {
    print("game over")
    timer.invalidate()    //Only use this line if you actually are using a timer and want to invalidate it here
}
```

Comment: The gameOver() method above didn't trigger when the snake.head.frame intersects its body. Where and how should I call this method?